# Why is the exception message for the wrong month being printed out differently than for my days and years?

Tags: java, exception, javafx

I am creating a gui for calculating the time between two dates and handling and exceptions that may occur. When handling days and years exceptions I am getting the desired exception handling message but when handling months it gives me the default message despite passing a string in the constructor.

Main file code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.time.DateTimeException;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.Period;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;


public class Lab9 extends Application {
    private Pane display;
    private TextField startDate;
    private TextField endDate;
    private Button countButton;
    int years;
    int months;
    int days;
    long numberOfDays;


    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage){
        display = new Pane(dates());

        CountClick countClick = new CountClick();
        countButton.setOnAction(countClick);

        Scene scene = new Scene(display);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
    private HBox startDate(){
        Label label = new Label("Start Date:");
        Font font = new Font("arial",13);
        label.setFont(font);
        startDate = new TextField("1/1/2000");
        HBox sBox = new HBox(5,label,startDate);
        sBox.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        sBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        return sBox;
    }

    private HBox endDate(){
        String day = ""+LocalDateTime.now().getDayOfMonth();
        String month = ""+LocalDateTime.now().getMonthValue();
        String year = ""+LocalDateTime.now().getYear();
        Label label = new Label("End Date:");
        Font font = new Font("arial",13);
        label.setFont(font);
        endDate = new TextField(day + "/" + month + "/" + year);
        HBox eBox = new HBox(5,label,endDate);
        eBox.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        eBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        return eBox;
    }

    private Button countButton(){
        countButton = new Button("Count");
        return countButton;
    }

    private VBox dates(){
        VBox dates = new VBox(10, startDate(),endDate(),countButton());
        dates.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        dates.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        return dates;
    }

    private void getInfo(){
        try {

            DataVerifier dv = new DataVerifier();
            dv.check("Start Date: ", startDate.getText());
            dv.check("End Date: ", endDate.getText());

            String[] startDates = startDate.getText().split("/");
            int startDay = Integer.parseInt(startDates[0]);
            int startMonth = Integer.parseInt(startDates[1]);
            int startYear = Integer.parseInt(startDates[2]);

            String[] endDates = endDate.getText().split("/");
            int endDay = Integer.parseInt(endDates[0]);
            int endMonth = Integer.parseInt(endDates[1]);
            int endYear = Integer.parseInt(endDates[2]);


            LocalDate start = LocalDate.of(startYear, startMonth, startDay);
            LocalDate end = LocalDate.of(endYear, endMonth, endDay);

            Period duration = Period.between(start, end);
            years = duration.getYears();
            months = duration.getMonths();
            days = duration.getDays();

            numberOfDays = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(start, end);

            String times = days + " days\n";
            times = times + months + " months\n";
            times = times + years + " years\n";
            times = times + numberOfDays + " total days";

            createPopup(times);
        }
        catch (DateTimeException de){
            createPopup(de.getMessage());
        }
        catch (CPSC1181Exception ce){
            createPopup(ce.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void createPopup(String message){
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        VBox popup = new VBox();
        popup.getChildren().add(new Text(message));
        Scene scene = new Scene(popup,300,200);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        stage.show();
    }

    private class CountClick implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            getInfo();
        }
    }
}
```

Exception Handler Class Code:

```
import java.time.DateTimeException;
import java.time.YearMonth;

public class DataVerifier {

    public void check (String type, String date) throws DateTimeException,CPSC1181Exception {

        // Get Dates
        String[] dates = date.split("/");
        int day = Integer.parseInt(dates[0]);
        int month = Integer.parseInt(dates[1]);
        int year = Integer.parseInt(dates[2]);

        YearMonth startYearMonth = YearMonth.of(year,month);

        // Check if length of input is too short or too long
        if (date.length() < "D/M/YYYY".length() || date.length() > "DD/MM/YYY".length()){
            throw new CPSC1181Exception(type + "not the right number of characters\nuse the following format\n" + "DD/MM/YYYY");
        }

        // Check if year is under 1000 or over 3000
        if (year < 1000 || year > 3000){
            throw new DateTimeException(type + "incorrect \"year digits\" of " + year);
        }

        // Check if month is under 1 or over 12
        if (month < 1 || month > 12){
            throw new DateTimeException(type + "incorrect \"month digits\" of " + month);
        }

        // Check if day is valid day in month
        if (day < 1 || day > startYearMonth.lengthOfMonth()){
            throw new DateTimeException(type + "incorrect \"day digits\" of " + day);
        }
    }
}
```

What is being outputted:

[image]

Desired Output:

[image]

Comment: You already get that exception from calling `YearMonth.of(year,month)`, before you even check the month.

Comment: Because [`YearMonth#of(int,int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/YearMonth.html#of(int,int)) is defined to throw a `DateTimeException` "_if either field value is invalid_".

Comment: how can i change that so my exception message will show instead?

Comment: Create the `YearMonth` _after_ you've checked the `year` and `month` values yourself?

Comment: Personally, I would just try to parse the text into a `LocalDate` using a `DateTimeFormatter` with the pattern `d/M/uuuu`, and if that threw a `DateTimeParseException` then just alert the user they input an invalid date and tell them the format they need to use. That loses some specificity in the error message, but it means you don't have to implement the parsing yourself. After you have the `LocalDate` you can check the year to make sure it's in the range you want.

Comment: As an aside, given you're using JavaFX, consider if using a [`DatePicker`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/DatePicker.html) would better fit your needs.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion and idea. I think DatePicker would be a good addition to the program.